# How to identify imageviews created programatically?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, photo

I'm trying to do an app to make photos and post it in a layout. The next code make this, but I do not know how to identify each imageview if I got 10 photos.

```
package com.selectphoto.dialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.selectphoto.R;
import com.selectphoto.ui.SelectPhotoBase;

import java.io.File;

public class TakePictureDialog extends Activity {

    private Uri outputFileUri;
    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 100;
    private LinearLayout layout_add_photo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_photo);

        final Button bt_return = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_return);
        final Button bt_take_photo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_take_photo);

        bt_return.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        bt_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openTakePicture();
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Call the camera app to take a picture.
     */
    public void openTakePicture() {
        // Create an output file.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Generate the Intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        // Launch the camera app.
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        layout_add_photo = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_photo);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            if(data != null){
                if(WorldersBase.DEBUG)
                    Log.e(WorldersBase.TAG, "Error en onActivityResult if");
                if(data.hasExtra("data")){
                    Bitmap thumbnail = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                    // Añadir al layout la imagen.
                }
            } else{
                if(WorldersBase.DEBUG)
                    Log.e(WorldersBase.TAG, "Error en onActivityResult else");
                // If there is no thumbnail image data, the image will have been stored in the
                // target output URI.

                // Resize the full image to fit in out image view.
                int width = layout_add_photo.getWidth();
                int height = 40;

                BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(), factoryOptions);

                int imageWidth = factoryOptions.outWidth;
                int imageHeight = factoryOptions.outHeight;

                // Determine how much to scale down the image.
                int scaleFactor = Math.min(imageWidth/width, imageHeight/height);

                // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View.
                factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                factoryOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                factoryOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(), factoryOptions);

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                layout_add_photo.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And another question is that I need to resize the pictures to a smaller size, I think with 640x480 or so. But I'm a little lost following the tutorial of [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently - On developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). I have the next methods, but I think that it is to load a resource of the project, not a file (like a taken photo), so I don't know how to implement it. The methods are:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

---

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

How I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
imageview.setId(someintvalue);
```

Solves this buddy ;

Comment: Yes, or you can set the tag instead. Ids and tags can both be used to identify views.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution for that. Thank you, I will wait for the second question. ;)

Comment: I've never listened to set a tags @PhilipSheard I will search for some info about how to use it.